# How to retrieve data from MySQL with join query

Tags: mysql, go

I'm building a simple Go REST API with MySQL and I'm having some trouble querying the data when it comes to slightly more complicated queries. I have 2 models: books and genres. The model definitions in go are as below:

```
type Book struct {
    ID    string  `json:"id"`
    Title string  `json:"title"`
    Genre *Genre  `json:"genre"`
    Price float64 `json:"price"`
}


type Genre struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

In SQL, the book table has the fields id, title, price, and id_genre which is a foreign key.

The confusion is after performing the select which returns the rows, I'm not sure how to add the information to the Genre field when I'm looping through the rows

```
result, err := database.DB.Query("SELECT a.id_book, a.title, a.price, b.name, b.id_genre FROM bookshelf.books a JOIN bookshelf.genres b ON a.id_genre = b.id_genre")

for result.Next() {
    var book models.Book

    // ????
    err := result.Scan(&book.ID, &book.Title, &book.Price, &book.Genre )

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // ...more code
}
```

Clearly in the result.Scan method is wrong, but I'm not sure how to go about the genre part.

Is this the right approach or am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: Initialize the Genre field first, because as it stands it's a `nil` pointer and will cause panic when you try to reference its fields, and then pass in the pointers to the Genre's fields. i.e. `&book.Genre.Name`

Comment: I tried initialising the genre by adding var genre models.Genre  and then I added & book.Genre.Name, &book.Genre.ID in the scan method but I get the following error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Am I initialising it correctly? Sorry if it's a silly question, I'm pretty new to Go!

Comment: Ok I figured it out thanks for your help. In the scan method I had to assign the values to genre by doing &genre.Name, &genre. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of initializing a separate variable you can directly initialize the field `book.Genre = new(Genre)` and then use `&book.Genre.Name`. Or you can do it with the separate variable, whatever suits you better.

Comment: Ah I didn't know it was possible to initialize like that. I tried it and I prefer this way of doing it. Thansk mate!